# How do I create a salary/tax calculator?

Tags: vba

I need help in Visual Basic in where I have to create a program in where a user inputs a salary like $50,000 and it returns a tax rate like 25%.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim income, tax As Single

    income = InputBox(" What is your income?")
    Label1.Text = income


    If income < 20000 Then
        MsgBox(" Your income is below $20,000 and your tax rate is 17% ")
        tax = income * 0.17
    End If



    If income >= 20000 Then
        MsgBox(" Your income is above $20,000 and your tax rate is 25% ")
        tax = income * 0.25
    End If

    Label2.Text = tax & " is your tax"

    If income <= 60000 Then
        MsgBox(" Your income is below $60,000 and your tax rate is 25% ")
        tax = income * 0.25
    End If



    If income > 60000 Then
        MsgBox(" Your income is above $60,000 and your tax rate is 37% ")
        tax = income * 0.37
    End If

    Label2.Text = tax & " is your tax"
```

The issue I'm having with this code is that it repeats itself twice when I input a number.

Comment: You may want to look into using a `Select Case` instead. It would be much cleaner.

Comment: Yea, I used that for another program that calculates your mark to a letter grade, for this program I have to make it work with the If, Then Structure.

Comment: oh... homework then?

Comment: Yea, it's an assignment I have to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting two MsgBox's is expected.  Why?  Because you have four independent If statements that have overlapping conditions.  For example, an income of 15000 is both less than 20000 and less than or equal to 60000.

Using If/Then/ElseIf is the key to coding this correctly:

```
Dim income As Single, tax As Single

income = InputBox(" What is your income?")
Label1.Text = income

If income < 20000 Then
    MsgBox (" Your income is below $20,000 and your tax rate is 17% ")
    tax = income * 0.17
ElseIf income <= 60000 Then
    MsgBox (" Your income is below $60,000 and your tax rate is 25% ")
    tax = income * 0.25
ElseIf income > 60000 Then
    MsgBox (" Your income is above $60,000 and your tax rate is 37% ")
    tax = income * 0.37
End If

Label2.Text = tax & " is your tax"
```

Notice I also removed a redundant ElseIf statement.  One other tweak to your code was Dim'ing income the right way.